# Getting SHOW CREATE TABLE from a view, as if it were a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have access to a remote database, and I would like to dump the schema and data of several *views* onto my local machine and load this into my local database as *tables* in a quick and easy way.

I lack the user privileges to run `CREATE TABLE AS (SELECT * FROM target_view)`, otherwise this would be trivial to solve. In other words, I want to retrieve and recreate the "composite" schema of target_view *as if it were a table*.

I do *not* want the output of `SHOW CREATE VIEW`, as this only shows a complex `SELECT` statement with joins to various tables on remote I have limited ability to access. And a problem I'm seeing in MySQL 8.x is when I run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on the view, this command simply acts as an alias of `SHOW CREATE VIEW` (which is reasonable).

Frustratingly, I can run `DESCRIBE` and see the schema of these views as they were tables. I really just need to convert this information into a `CREATE TABLE` statement without actually being able to run `CREATE TABLE`.

In case it weren't obvious, the key is to avoid manual reconstruction of these views' tabular schemas (as they may change in the future). I also want to avoid the solution of reverse engineering a generic table construction of 20-30 generic VARCHAR or TEXT columns from a CSV dump.

Comment: You may find a good answer to this question at dba.stackexchange.com. It's borderline "admin" question.

Comment: Do you have privilege to run CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE? This does not require the CREATE privilege.

Comment: @BillKarwin great suggestion, but no, I get an 'Access denied' error.

Comment: Okay then you may not have that privilege either. You can confirm with the `SHOW GRANTS` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to display the metadata of a result set in CREATE TABLE syntax.

What I would do given your circumstance is first create on your local MySQL instance the base table and the view, then you can use the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...` syntax to produce a concrete table to match the metadata of the view result set.